# How to Show Veriable Value In Session Message?

Tags: php, session

have set `session['message']` for the alert message, I want to show the value of a variable `E.g: $link` in the message how can I show the value of the variable in below line.

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Your Order Is Submitted " ;
```

Comment: just use variable instead of static value like : = $link;

Comment: $_SESSION['message'] = $link;

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing you need to do;

```
$_SESSION['message'] = $link
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the value of $link at the end of your existing message:

```
$_SESSION['message'] .= $link;
```

If you want to return the message and not change your original message:

echo $_SESSION['message'] . $link;

Another option, if $link is defined before $_SESSION['message'] is:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Your Order Is Submitted {$link}";
```